# Get normalized click position on a RectTransform

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ive made a ui touch/click controller by using an UI image with collider. The ui is rendered with a stacked camera.

Im using IPointerDownHandler.OnPointerDown to get the click event.
The controller is supposed to give a value from 0-1 depending on how far up you click it.

Im using Canvas Scaler on the UI to make the controllers resize depending on device. But that messes up my calculations since the click position wont be the same. How is this supposed to be handled? Now the calculation is only correct when i disable Canvas Scaler or run it on a display with the default dimensions.

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
{

    SetAccelerationValue(pointerEventData.position.y);
}
    private void SetAccelerationValue(float posY)
{   
    float percentagePosition;
    var positionOnAccelerator = posY - minY;
    var acceleratorHeight = maxY - minY;
    percentagePosition = positionOnAccelerator / acceleratorHeight;
    

    Debug.Log(percentagePosition);

}
```

Comment: Did you try multiplying your `acceleratorHeight` and `positionOnAccelerator` by the transform scale?

Comment: No i didnt. Is it the transforms scale that is used by the Canvas Scaler then? I will try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) to get a position in the local space of the given [`RectTransform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html).

Then combine it with [`Rect.PointToNormalized`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.PointToNormalized.html)

> Returns the normalized coordinates cooresponding the the point.
>
> The returned `Vector2` is in the range 0 to 1 with values more 1 or less than zero clamped.

to get a normalized position within that [`RectTransform.rect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html) (0,0) being **bottom-left** corner, (1,1) being the **top-right** corner

```c#
[SerializeField] private RectTransform _rectTransform;

private void Awake ()
{
    if(!_rectTransform) _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

private bool GetNormalizedPosition(PointerEventData pointerEventData, out Vector2 normalizedPosition)
{   
    normalizedPosition = default;

    // get the pointer position in the local space of the UI element
    // NOTE: For click vents use "pointerEventData.pressEventCamera"
    // For hover events you would rather use "pointerEventData.enterEventCamera"
    if(!RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(_rectTransform, pointerEventData.position, pointerEventData.pressEventCamera, out var localPosition)) return false;
    
    normalizedPosition = Rect.PointToNormalized(_rectTransform.rect, localPosition);
    // I think this kind of equals doing something like
    //var rect = _rectTransform.rect;
    //var normalizedPosition = new Vector2 (
    //    (localPosition.x - rect.x) / rect.width, 
    //    (localPosition.y - rect.y) / rect.height);  

    Debug.Log(normalizedPosition);

    return true;
}
```

Since the normalized position returns values like

```c#
(0|1)-----(1|1)
  |         |
  |  (0|0)  |
  |         |
(0|0)-----(1|0)
```

but you sounds like what you want to get is

```c#
 (-1|1)----(1|1)
   |         |
   |   0|0   |
   |         |
(-1|-1)----(1|-1)
```

So you can simply shift the returned value using e.g.

```c#
// Shift the normalized Rect position from [0,0] (bottom-left), [1,1] (top-right)
// into [-1, -1] (bottom-left), [1,1] (top-right)
private static readonly Vector2 _multiplcator = Vector2.one * 2f;
private static readonly Vector2 _shifter = Vector2.one * 0.5f;

private static Vector2 GetShiftedNormalizedPosition(Vector2 normalizedPosition)
{
    return Vector2.Scale((normalizedPosition - _shifter), _multiplcator);
}
```

[image]

So finally you would use e.g.

```c#
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
{
    if(!GetNormalizedPosition(pointerEventData, out var normalizedPosition)) return;

    var shiftedNormalizedPosition = GetShiftedNormalizedPosition(normalizedPosition);

    SetAccelerationValue(shiftedNormalizedPosition.y);

    // And probably for your other question also
    SetSteeringValue(shiftedNormalizedPosition.x);
}
```

And of course within `SetAccelerationValue` you don't calculate anything but just set the value ;)

**This uses always the current rect so you don't have to store any min/max values and it also applies to any dynamic re-scaling of the rect.**

This would then probably also apply to your [other almost duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680792/get-corner-positions-of-ui-element-anchored-right) ;)

Comment: OMFG Thank you, thank you, thank you. It works in all situations as you said. This is also good study material. I can check out these convertion methods to figure out what i need to learn about screen and ui math. However, what is up with Unity. I cant wrap my head around that what im trying to do is so uncommon and hard to find a solution to. Ill make sure to pay it forward and help someone else.