# 2 Dimentional sliders in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider

I am trying to make a mobile game where the player is controlled by a 2D virtual joystick that I am trying to make on my own for learning purposes. I have tried using a slider for making a 1 Dimentional slider for horizontal player movement. To achieve 2 Dimentions... can I use 2 Slider on top of each other..? Like this guy did in his JS code: [Link to codepen.io](http://shorturl.at/axX48)
If this thing is possible.. can anyone please share any blog post or documentation about it as I tried searching for it but failed...

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me and from your description it is unclear what you are trying to achieve ... if anything can you please post a normal URL?

Comment: Do you mean [this one](https://codepen.io/tyler-murphy/pen/tHsAu)? So basically you want a rectangle and just get the normalized position within that rectangle? So basically you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680393/get-normalized-click-position-on-a-recttransform) as a start point .. from there when starting the interaction you only need to check whether you are close enough to your current knob position and only then start dragging the knob and update the position and normalized position accordingly